# How can I show people with their location on Google Maps?

Tags: google-search, google-maps, integration

I am running a Job portal website, I collect User's information including their latitude and longitude, I basically want them to be searchable on Google Maps from the information they provide to my website.

Similar Example include Uber, Lyft and Careem integration with Google Maps, Like whenever I put a direction in Google maps, I have an option to book rides from third party applications like Uber and Careem right from Google maps,
[this link](https://www.lifewire.com/order-uber-from-google-maps-4129106) explains how its done.

I basically want whenever somebody searches "Automobile Technicians near me" in Google, it shows PEOPLE registered in my site (having their latitude and longitude in my database), into Google maps search and a link to my Application so that whenever somebody clicks to "Call" or contact them, it redirects to my application. Similar to its doing with Ride sharing Service providers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you follow closely **the information placed over the directions** provided on the mentioned site , you notice that:

> .... It's no surprise, then, that **these two high-profile apps**
>   could work together. Google Maps and the ride-sharing service Uber
>   **have offered some level of integration for some time** — you have been able to view the price and time of different Uber options
>   alongside transportation choices since 2014.
>
> **However, more recently the two companies extended this partnership to allow you to book a ride with Uber directly from the Google Maps
>   app on your phone**. That means you don't have to switch over to the
>   Uber app after pulling up directions on Maps, comparing your choices,
>   viewing prices and settling on this ride-sharing service. The process
>   of booking happens seamlessly, without requiring much manual work on
>   your end.

Given that, you can not *"just do it" (Similar to its doing with Ride sharing Service providers)*.

Comment: Sad to listen that, any idea how can someone request a feature from Google? atleast I can request a feature like this from Google